# How to drop the documentation rule for the constructor?

Tags: c#, asp.net, stylecop

I am using StyleCop, and I want to remove the documentation for the constructors only -I want to keep it for the methods, properties, etc.-, that is because I felt that the constructor documentation is almost useless, so for example:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="TextBuilder"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="text">.</param>
    public TextBuilder(string text)
    {
        ArgumentValidator.ThrowIfNullOrWhitespace(nameof(text), text);
        this.text = text;
    }
```

We all know that the constructor is to initialize a new instance of the class, so is there anyway to do this? for example a suppression role or something like that, thanks in advance.

Comment: are you using resharper as well?

Comment: You should document constructors. you may need to describe your parameters.

Comment: You should document constructors also - if you have to write a constructor, you need to make it clear to whom ever is using your class what this constructor is doing.

Comment: @Train No, I doesn't use it.

Comment: @GlennFerrie I know that sometimes I need to document it, but I want to know that if I can make the documentation for the constructor optional.

Comment: @ZoharPeled I know that sometimes I need to document it, but I want to know that if I can make the documentation for the constructor optional